# How to remove selected columns from dynamically generated html-table?

Tags: php, html, mysql, html-table

I have an SQL-database where I read out data that are then shown in a dynamically generated html-table. Here is my code that works fine:

```
$sql = "SELECT $selection FROM $tabelle WHERE $masterarray";


$result = mysqli_query($db, $sql) or die("Invalid query");             
$numrows = mysqli_num_rows($result);  
$numcols = mysqli_num_fields($result); 
$field = mysqli_fetch_fields($result); 


if ($numrows > 0) {

echo "<table>";
echo "<thead>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th>" . 'Nr' . "</th>";


for($x=0;$x<$numcols;$x++){
echo "<th>" . $field[$x]->name . "</th>";
}

echo "</tr>";
echo "</thead>";

echo "<tbody>";
echo "<tr>";
$nr = 1;

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo "<td>" . $nr . "</td>";
  for ($k=0; $k<$numcols; $k++) {    
  echo "<td>" . $row[$k] . "</td>"; //Prints the data
  }

 $nr = $nr + 1;
 echo "</tr>";

 }
 echo "</tbody>";
 echo "</table>";

}
}

mysqli_close($db);
```

Now, I want to remove specific columns (e.g. those, which are empty or those, which are not that interesting for the user, who makes the request).

I tried it with `unset($field[$variable])`, however, it didn't work. In addition, the values (if there are any), should be removed, too.

Comment: If you can, switch from `mysqli` to `PDO`: you will then be able to do a simple `fetchAll` and use `array_column` to iterate over each column and check whether it's an interesting one.

Answer (score 1):

Always format the array before you print it. Try to remove the specific columns from the `$field` array before you echo the HTML and then print the final table. Once the HTML code is echoed in PHP you won't be able to remove it without the use of JavaScript.

You can check against the `$field[$x]->name` variable and use `continue` to skip the column.

Comment: That´s exactly, what I would like to do! How can I check against the $field[$x]->name variable to skip the column?

Answer (score 1):

can let mysql filter them out for you,
`$sql = "SELECT $selection FROM $tabelle WHERE $masterarray AND LENGTH($selection) > 0";`

-- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_length

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

//  DataBase Config - http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdo.construct.php.
$dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test';
$usr = 'root';
$pwd = '';

try {   //  try to connect in database.

    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $usr, $pwd);

} catch (PDOException $e) { //  if there is error in the connection.

    die('Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage());

}

//  Prepare Statement and execute - http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdo.prepare.php.
$stm = $pdo->prepare('select id, weight, color, name from product');
$stm->execute();

//  Get ALL rows - Object.
$rows = $stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

//  Print Rows.
//echo '<pre>'.print_r(rows, true).'</pre>';

//  Check $row;
if (count($rows)) {

    //  Order and Display Cols.
    $colsDisplay = [
        'id'        => 'ID Product',
        'name'      => 'Name',
        'weight'    => 'Weigth'
    ];

    //  Table.
    $html = '<table border="1">';
    $html .= "\n    <thead>";
    $html .= "\n        <tr>";
    $html .= "\n            <th  bgcolor='#eee'>Row</th>";
    $html .= "\n            <th>". implode("</th>\n         <th>", $colsDisplay) ."</th>";
    $html .= "\n        </tr>";
    $html .= "\n    </thead>";
    $html .= "\n    <tbody>";

    //  Loop ROWS.
    foreach ($rows as $key => $val) {

        $html .= "\n        <tr>";

        $html .= "\n            <td bgcolor='#eee'>". $key ."</td>";

        //  Loop COLS to display.
        foreach ($colsDisplay as $thKey => $thVal) {

            $html .= "\n            <td>". $val->$thKey ."</td>";

        }

        $html .= "\n        </tr>";

    }

    $html .= "\n".' </tbody>';
    $html .= "\n".'</table>';

    echo $html;

}
```

Comment: Thank you Geraldo for your solution! That´s exactly, what I want to do and it works perfectly with your $rows-array! However, when I try to put it into my code, I alway get a table with the right column names but with 6 empty rows. I think the problem must be in my database query. I get my results from the database with $rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result), which works with my old code but´unfortunately not with your solution. Could you please give me an example how I have to do my database-query to get my $rows?

Comment: I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

In order to know that a column is empty, you should check the whole column. There are different ways to do it, one of them could be investigating which of them are empty and then only using those that aren't empty. Something like this:

```
<?php
// ... 
$q = "SELECT SUM(LENGTH(my_first_column)) col_0, SUM(LENGTH(my_second_column)) col_1, ..., SUM(LENGTH(my_11th_column)) col_10 FROM $tabelle WHERE $masterarray";

// ... execute query and return results in $nonEmpty
$nonEmpty = array();
foreach($row as $columnIndex) {
  if ($row[$columnIndex] > 0) {
     $nonEmpty[] = $columnIndex;
  }
}
// ... now go through results and print only cols with at least one row with lenght > 0 i.e. non empty
$len = 11;
$rowHTML = "<tr>";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

   for ($i = 0; $i < $len; ++$i) {
      $rowHTML = '';
      if (!in_array($i, $nonEmpty)) {
         $rowHTML .= '<td>' . $row[$i] . '</td>';
      }
      $rowHTML .= "</tr>\n";
   }
}

// ...
```

This chunk of code will remove columns with ALL empty values. If you have at least one cell in the column with some value, you'll see the column in your result.

The code isn't optimized - it's just a rough idea. But it's a starting point.